# Equal cost multipath Dijkstra's Algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm, dijkstra

Using python recipes proposed here:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/119466-dijkstras-algorithm-for-shortest-paths/

and

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117228-priority-dictionary/

and using as input the following graph:

```
 graph_2  = {
    'R1':{'R2':5,'R3':5},
    'R2':{'R1':5,'R4':5},
    'R3':{'R1':5,'R4':5},
    'R4':{'R2':5,'R3':5},
}
```

I'm trying to get ALL shortest paths between R1 and R4.  However, I'm only getting one shortest path (R1-R2-R4), and not (R1-R3-R4).  I need to simulate ECMP (such as OSPF does).  What I need is that function shortestPath returns all shortest path (i.e [[R1-R2-R4],[R1-R3-R4]]) in case of Equal Cost Multipath (like graph_2 on top) and only the shortest path in case of Single Path like for example:

```
  graph_3  = {
    'R1':{'R2':5,'R3':5},
    'R2':{'R1':5,'R4':5},
    'R3':{'R1':5,'R4':10},
    'R4':{'R2':5,'R3':5},
}
```

I've modified the code in the Dijkstra function like that:

```
from priodict import priorityDictionary

graph_2  = {

'R1':{'R2':5,'R3':5},
'R2':{'R1':5,'R4':5},
'R3':{'R1':5,'R4':5},
'R4':{'R2':5,'R3':5},
}



def Dijkstra(G,start,end=None):

    D = {}  # dictionary of final distances
    P = {}  # dictionary of predecessors
    Q = priorityDictionary()   # est.dist. of non-final vert.
    Q[start] = 0
    for v in Q:
        D[v] = Q[v]
        if v == end: break

        for w in G[v]:
            vwLength = D[v] + G[v][w]

            if w in D:
                if vwLength < D[w]:
                    raise ValueError, \
            elif w not in Q or vwLength < Q[w]:
                Q[w] = vwLength
                P[w] = [v]
            elif  w not in Q or vwLength == Q[w]: <---adding this part
                Q[w] = vwLength
                P[w] += [v]

    return (D,P)

def shortestPath(G,start,end):
    D,P = Dijkstra(G,start,end)
    print D,P
    Path = []
    while 1:
        Path.append(end)
        print end
        if end == start: break
        end = P[end]
    Path.reverse()
    return Path

print shortestPath(graph_2,'R1','R4')
```

and I'm getting the following output and error:

```
{'R4': 10, 'R1': 0, 'R2': 5, 'R3': 5} {'R4': ['R2', 'R3'], 'R2': ['R1'], 'R3': ['R1']}

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "next-hop-resolver.py", line 194, in <module>
print shortestPath(graph_2,'R1','R4')
File "next-hop-resolver.py", line 172, in shortestPath
end = P[end]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

What I would like to get using graph_2 is :

[['R1', 'R2', 'R4'], ['R1', 'R3', 'R4']]

and using graph_3:

[['R1', 'R2', 'R4']]

If I execute the code as is, i.e without any kind of code modification I get the following result, no matter if I use graph_2 or graph_3:

[['R1', 'R2', 'R4']]

i.e always the shortest path, even if there is more than one path.

I know that a list can't be a key in a dictionary, but to be honest I'm stuck with that, so any help is more than welcome

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
Your code has indentation problems, a few syntax errors, and is missing at least one external variable.  This keeps us from accurately reproducing the problem.

Comment: I've modified the code adding the part was missing and trying to improve the explanation of the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I think I got what I was looking for :)

Here's the final code

```
from priodict import priorityDictionary
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict
import sys
graph_2  = {

'R1':{'R2':5,'R3':5},
'R2':{'R1':5,'R4':5},
'R3':{'R1':5,'R4':5},
'R4':{'R2':5,'R3':5,'R5':5},
'R5':{'R4':5}

}

graph_3 = {

'192.168.255.1':{'192.168.255.2':10,'192.168.255.3':10},
'192.168.255.2':{'192.168.255.1':10,'192.168.255.3':50},
'192.168.255.3':{'192.168.255.1':20,'192.168.255.2':50},
'192.168.255.4':{'192.168.255.3':20},
'192.168.255.3':{'192.168.255.4':20}
}

graph_4 = {
'R1':{'R2':5},
'R2':{'R1':5},
'R2':{'R3':5},
'R3':{'R2':5},
'R3':{'R4':5},
'R4':{'R3':5}
}

graph_5 = {

'A':{'B':5,'C':10,'E':2},
'B':{'A':5,'C':5},
'C':{'B':5,'A':10,'E':8,'D':4},
'D':{'C':4,'E':5},
'E':{'A':2,'D':5,'C':8}

}

def Dijkstra(g,start,end=None):

    d = {}  # dictionary of final distances
    p = {}  # dictionary of predecessors
    q = priorityDictionary()   # est.dist. of non-final vert.
    q[start] = 0
    for v in q:
        d[v] = q[v]
        if v == end: break      
        for w in g[v]:
            vwLength = d[v] + g[v][w]
            if w in d:
                if vwLength < d[w]:
                    raise ValueError
            elif w not in q or vwLength < q[w]:
                q[w] = vwLength
                p[w] = [v]
            elif  w not in q or vwLength == q[w]:
                q[w] = vwLength
                p[w] += [v] 
    return (d,p)        

def shortestPath(g,start,end):

    d,p = Dijkstra(g,start,end)
    path = [[end]]
    while True:
        if len(p[end]) > 1:
            path.append(p[end])
            for node in p[end]:
                if node != start:
                    if ''.join(p[end]) == start: break
                    end = node
        path.append(p[end])
        if ''.join(p[end]) == start: break
        for node in p[end]:
            if node == start: break
            end = node  
    return path[::-1]


print shortestPath(graph_2,'R1','R5')
print shortestPath(graph_3,'192.168.255.1','192.168.255.2')
print shortestPath(graph_4,'R1','R4')
print shortestPath(graph_5,'A','C')
```

and the output for each graph :

```
[['R1'], ['R2', 'R3'], ['R4'], ['R5']]
[['192.168.255.1'], ['192.168.255.2']]
[['R1'], ['R2'], ['R3'], ['R4']]
[['A'], ['A', 'E', 'B'], ['C']]
```

Answer (score 0):

**ANALYSIS**

Thanks for providing runnable code.  You haven't explained your design, but the functional problem is clear enough: **P** is responsible for returning the predecessor of any given node along the present path.  Since a path is strictly linear, there can be only one predecessor.  The **while** loop in **shortestPath** depends on this.

However, the **P** you returned lists *two* predecessors for **R4** along the present path, and you immediately try to index **P** with both of them at once.  You can't do that; you have to handle each path individually.

**SOLUTION**

Simply fixing your code is tantamount to doing your homework for you; i.e. not cool.  Since you're already this far, I suggest that you alter the loop in **shortestPath** to work through multiple paths.  Start with the idea of working on *each* of the returned values, in turn, one at a time:

```
while True:
    for node in end:
        # continue with single-path code
```

**CODING NOTE**

Yes, I changed the loop condition form **1** to **True**.
The recipes you're using appear to be written by someone who translated from **C** or other early 3rd-generation language, without learning present-day coding improvements.  One-letter variable names, capital letters, etc. are sub-standard habits for today's programmers.  (I've had to re-learn a few, myself.)

To get an idea of what you can work toward, see [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Thanks for your tips @Prune